# Include all codeigniter functions to a new static page(php file) which is located in root folder

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-url

I am developing a website which having many static pages. so i created controller only for dynamic pages(it might be wrong practice). Keeping all other static files in root folder. Now i want to use base_url() function from codeigniter for the static pages which is located in root folder. But i am not sure im am doing good practice or not. so ** Please give me a solution to manage many static page in codeigniter. **

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a controller with name Static_page send all your static pages requests to this controller

Static controller

```
class Static_Page extends CI_Controller{


    function index(){
       $page = $this->uri->segment(1,'default_static_page');
       if (!file_exists(APPPATH."views/{$page}.php"))
         {
           show_404();
         } 
       $this->load->view($page);
   }

}
```

save all your static pages as views with same name as uri you will call like if you call http://your-site.com/about-us your view will be about-us.php, http://your-site.com/contact your view will be contact.php

Comment: I think i can get all function by including a CI file and extending it's class.. I am searching for that file name and class name..

Comment: @umefarook your class is useful. :)

Answer (score 0):

It's not as simple as just including the file path to the helper/library that you want. If we use the URL Helper as an example, you'll notice at the top of the file, this line:

```
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
```

This means if `BASEPATH` isn't defined you won't be able to access the file. Assume you have a static page in your root, called `my_static_page.php`. You could define `BASEPATH` and include the file, like this:

```
define('BASEPATH',true);
require_once 'system/helpers/url_helper.php';
```

This will allow you to access to the script, but it's doesn't necessarily mean that all of the functions will work. For example, the `anchor` function will work, but the `base_url` won't. Certain functions may have certain dependencies, requiring functionality from other components of CodeIgniter.

By accessing files directly in the root of your project, you are effectively bypassing CodeIgniter's `index.php` file. This file will ensure that all of the required paths are setup, that base classes are instantiated, global functions are available etc. CodeIgniter's loading function (`$this->load->helper('url');`), which would also not be used in this scenario, would load/provide access to the CI instance amongst other things, which you can see is required in the `base_url` function:

```
function base_url($uri = '')
{
    $CI =& get_instance();
    return $CI->config->base_url($uri);
}
```

In short, it would take considerable time and effort to ensure that all of CodeIgniter's functionality is available to other files in the root. It also negates many of the useful features provided by the framework, and the encouraged MVC design pattern. I'd suggest loading your static pages as views, using a controller - you may find [this tutorial](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/tutorial/static_pages.html) from CodeIgniter's user guide particularly useful.

Comment: After seeing your edit, what you're doing isn't best practice. I'd just store the static pages as _views_ and load them from a controller - no need to put them in the root.